# what is the optimal texture size in this case?

Tags: opengl-es, textures

what is the optimal texture size in this case for pixel perfect fit on screen and for performance?
Target: background texture for a device with 480x800 resolution

a.
480x800 image resized to: 512x1024

b.
512x1024 texture contains a 480x800 region and 
u = 0.0 .. 0.9375 (480/512)
v = 0.0 .. 0.78125 (800/1024)

c.
original image (480x800) as texture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option c. should be avoided as many devices are only power-of-two compatible. b. should be faster than a. since not as many texels have to be fetched from the texture memory. I doubt however that you will notice any difference in fps as at 480x800 you're most likely to be fillrate-limited more than anything else.

And yes, you can get pixel-perfect mapping using b. if you set your texcoords correctly, I'm using a texture atlas giving p-p results for my app.